# switching windows in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

Is it possible to work on multiple windows using selenium, when I searched on the net, there are only explanations and codes available for Selenium2 webdriver version. For the normal selenium I can't find any info on it. So is there a way multiple window operations be performed in selenium + java , if yes, how can it be achieved?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can try selenium.selectwindow . Details are [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.SelectWindow.html)